# 2d Grid Generation (Unity C#)

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, grid

I am creating a simple program in Unity C# that will generate a 2d grid using a 2d sprite prefab. I am stuck here, I don't know what to do. When ran, I receive an error.

```
Assets/Generator.cs(22,75): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `grid_object'
```

I am a beginner, so I'm not sure what to do. This is most likely a rookie mistake, so thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Generator : MonoBehaviour {

public float Width = 20;
public float Height = 20;
public Transform grid_object;
private GameObject [,] grid = new GameObject[20,20];


void Start () {
    CreateGrid();
}


private void CreateGrid() {

    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
            GameObject grid_object = (GameObject)Instantiate(grid_object);
            grid_object.transform.position = new Vector2(
                grid_object.transform.position.x+x, 
                grid_object.transform.position.y+y);
            grid[x,y] = grid_object;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: A core requirement, in programming, is that you give variables *unique names*. Your issue comes from having two variables labelled "`grid_object`". Hopefully, this answers your question; this is ultimately a *generic programming* question, as this is something that is *not specific to game development*. We don't consider these sort of questions on topic for GameDevSE, but feel free to look for more information at StackOverflow.

Comment: [This is example of 2d grid generation](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134000/unity-2d-coordinates/134001#134001) that will help you

Answer (score 1):

Your Transform grid_object and your GameObject grid_object have the same name. Change one of them to something different and it should work.